# In cmd python shows python 2.7 installed but when I write python2 it shows that it isn't recognized as a internal file or command

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

```
C:\Users\User>python2
'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\User>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Altough I do have python installed when I type python2 in my cmd it doesn't see it.

Comment: windows doesn't know what 'python2' is. Why do you need it to?

Comment: And why do you expect it to be `python2`? Clearly it is just `python`.

Comment: Then I don't need really need it?

Comment: I'm currently using hatch but it doesn't open my chrome browser so I thought that maybe it had something to do with that I was using the python command instead of the python2 command

Comment: no. your 'python' command is still opening python 2.7

Comment: ```DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:4963/devtools/browser/38d51d55-7c68-4939-94eb-86bec7aaff5e
[13096:8132:0709/173854.294:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:38:54.294] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[13096:8132:0709/173854.304:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:38:54.303] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
``` this is the code I get when entering ```python main.py``` on hatch in cmd

Comment: Add any errors, or other info to the actual question, not as comments.

Answer (score -3):

You can rename your python.exe into python2.exe and set the enviromental PATH properly to this renamed exe. Afterwards you can use python2 as an alias from command line (cmd)

Comment: Doing this leads to all sorts of confusion later.  It would be better to create shortcuts/symbolic links to accomplish the same effect.